# Laravel - 4: How to add custom fields to AUTH module

Tags: php, laravel

```
$cred = array(
    'username' => $post['username'],
    'password1' => md5($post['password1']),
    'password2' => md5($post['password2']) // custom third field
);

// Check all for authentication
Auth::attempt($cred);
```

How to add custom fields to `AUTH` module ?

Comment: If I assume those are post variables from `<form>`.. then you should like `$_POST['username']`

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran I mean how to make the module to authenticate the user using the custom 'username' and 'password1' and 'password2' instead of the standard 'login' and 'password'

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran With Laravel you'd use `Input::get('name')` not the global variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't, instead you may try something like this:

```
$cred = array(
    'username' => Input::get('username'),
    'password' => Input::get('password1')
);

// At first normally check the credentials using validate method
// but doesn't login, if check succeeded then check the second
// password manually, using your encrypted password2 field
if(Auth::validate($cred)) {
    // Now check the password2, assumed you're using md5
    // hashing for this field (according to your question)
    $password2 = md5(Input::get('password2'));
    $user = User::where('username', $cred['username'])->first();
    if( $user->password2 == $password2) {
        // Now manually login the user
        Auth::login($user);
        return Redirect::to('url'); // successful login url
    }
    else{
        // Password2 missmatched
        $validator = Validator::make(array(), array())->getMessagebag();
        $validator->add('errorLogin', 'Invalid Credentials!');
        return Redirect::back()->withInput()->withError($validator);
    }
}
else {
    // Didn't pass even the first validation (username, password1)
    $validator = Validator::make(array(), array())->getMessagebag();
    $validator->add('errorLogin', 'Invalid Credentials!');
    return Redirect::back()->withInput()->withError($validator);
}
```

In the `view` you can use this to show error message on failed login:

```
{{ $errors->first('errorLogin') }} // Invalid Credentials!
```

For the first `validate` methos don't use any encryption, let Laravel do it as it does and for the second password you may use your own encryption.

Comment: You always want to handle validation before touching the database. On top of that, if you're comparing passwords, you'd want to do `Hash::check('password', 'hashofpassword')`. This isn't required here though, as you can just do a same, THEN log the user in. I'd also like to add that attempting to get a user to supply their password twice to login, is a horrible idea.

Comment: @ollieread! Just read the question first and then see my answer. OP is using two different fields for password and he has one password saved in to database using md5 hash and another one using normal way, so he must use this things. At least you should have thought that, OP accepted it because it solved the problem. It's not about how to implement the full authentication but just to how can (s)he use two different password to authenticate a user, I omitted validation intentionally, just focused on the solution.

Comment: I think you'll find that the password was an example field. You can tell this by the fact that both password1 and password2 are using `md5()`. Also, you shouldn't authenticate a user using two different passwords and you most definitely should not use a plain md5. You're encouraging bad code. As stated in the initial question, it was how to use the `Auth` library while passing in another credential. Your answer is horrendously wrong.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to have the user matched with another credential/where clause, then simply pass it into the credentials array. For example:

```
<?php
$credentials = [
    'username' => Input::get('username'),
    'password' => Input::get('password'),
    'active'   => 1
];

if(Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
    // code here
}
```

If you wanted to check a confirm password, like the above suggestion, you'd want to check this first, before checking anything else, not after.

```
<?php
$validate = [
    'password' => Input::get('password'),
    'password_confirmation' => Input::get('password_confirmation')
];

$validator = Validator::make(
    $validate,
    ['password' => ['same:password_confirmation']]
);

// now you make a credentials array and attempt to auth
```

Comment: It's not same password, two different password fields with two different hashed values and one is uing `md5`.

Comment: @SheikhHeera where did you get this information from? I see no mention of this what so ever. It seems unfair to vote someone down for information that isn't anywhere. The original question is about adding extra fields to an auth call.

Comment: Read the comments, `how to make the module to authenticate the user using the custom 'username' and 'password1' and 'password2' instead of the standard 'login' and 'password'`, I didn't encourage to do it but it was `OP`'s need and I solved it another way and answer got accepted but yes I'll write about the best practices (Laravel) on my upcoming book on Laravel.

Comment: Everything aside, you have answered with several lines of code, when all of that could be simplified into my first block of code.

Comment: In my opinion this is the correct answer. Needed a slight edit but works like a charm for me. I think OP is needing this answer. At least, when someone googles this, right here is the correct answer to the question that is asked. If this is not the answer that OP was looking for, the question wasn't good.

Comment: For those who suggested the edit, [] is correct for array notation. I also chose to use [] because of the limit space we have.

Answer (score 0):

You must send an array with `username` and `password` to the `Auth::attempt` method

You can fill those with whatever you need though, in your case it would be something like this:

```
$post = Input::all(); // I assume this is how you are filling the $post variable?
Auth::attempt(array('username' => $post['username'], 'password' => $post['password1']);
```

Note that you do not need to hash the password, the attempt method will handle that. You also do not need to send the second password along with it, it will completely ignore everything except 'username' and 'password'

Comment: Actually it only requires 'password' and with not ignore everything else.